# Show my own Methods/Properties of a MS .NET class always at top in Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, methods, intellisense, show

I have a UserControl and I put some public Methods/Properties in there.

I would like to have that when the user of my UserControl types something and Intellisense opens, that he immediately sees my custom methods created in the UserControl, is that possible somehow by marking the methods/props with kind of attributes?

Comment: Prefix your method names with "Aardvark".

Comment: then my boss is killing me for choosing such a bad name ;-) thx though Hans.

Comment: Great question, and don't know why you weren't upvoted more. There are C# classes I have wrapped up with simpler methods, and I'd love those to come on top. Anyway I upvoted/favourited you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not something that can be easily done. Visual Studio will sort the methods/properties alphabetically.

To do what you want, you will need to:

- Mark your methods/properties with a custom attribute
- Write this custom attribute
- Use VS automation to reflect over *every* type to find this attribute
- Reorder the intellisense listing (not sure if this is even possible with VS VBA)